# My introduction to Compile

Tags: plotting, performance-tuning, compile, fractals

I am reading Fractals from the Newton-Raphson method from [Peter Young's page](http://young.physics.ucsc.edu/115/).

I've tried:

```
newtC = Compile[{{n, _Integer}, {z, _Complex}},
  Arg[FixedPoint[# - (#^n - 1)/(n #^(n - 1)) &, N[z], 50]]/(2 Pi)]
```

And:

```
Timing[DensityPlot[newtC[3, x + I y], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, PlotPoints -> 300]]
```

Gave me this image in 3.96397:

[image]

Now, I tried:

```
newt[n_, z_] := 
 Arg[FixedPoint[# - (#^n - 1)/(n #^(n - 1)) &, N[z], 50]]/(2 Pi)
```

Then, even when I eliminated the `PlotPoints->300`, the following code will not work:

```
Timing[DensityPlot[newt[3, x + I y], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}]]
```

I can't even abort the run: I have to quit the kernel. I'm really surprised at this huge difference. Am I missing something?

Comment: The docs have [a similar example](http://wolfram.com/xid/0giqxe-cadgg9).

Answer (score 10):

Indeed, the `newt` function as you wrote it freezes *Mathematica* at least for a minute or so (I aborted it afterwards without waiting to see if it would complete).

Instead, you can prevent any attempts at symbolically evaluating the `newt` function by `DensityPlot` by restricting it to numerical arguments only:

```
Clear[newt]
newt[n_?NumericQ, z_?NumericQ] := 
 Arg[FixedPoint[# - (#^n - 1)/(n #^(n - 1)) &, N[z], 50]]/(2 Pi)

Timing[DensityPlot[newt[3, x + I y], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, PlotPoints -> 300]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Your compiled version of this function has a nice speed edge over the non-compiled one: on my system it takes only 3.5 s to generate the same density plot using your `newtC`.

Comment: Thanks. Just so everyone knows, this isn't mine, but it comes from a great page: [http://young.physics.ucsc.edu/115/](http://young.physics.ucsc.edu/115/).

Comment: @David if you want to make the attribution more visible and permanent, then you should add it to your question.

Comment: @YvesKlett Good point, I've done it.

Comment: @MarcoB I tried your approach and it only took 11.5376. You are saying restricting to numerical arguments only, yet the original function `newt[n_, z_] := 
 Arg[FixedPoint[# - (#^n - 1)/(n #^(n - 1)) &, N[z], 50]]/(2 Pi)`, if I change FixedPoint to FixedPointList, `Clear[newt]
newt[n_, z_] := 
 Arg[FixedPointList[# - (#^n - 1)/(n #^(n - 1)) &, N[z], 50]]/(2 Pi)`, does seem to produce numeric arguments only:  `newt[3, -0.75 - 0.5 I]' produces `{-0.406416, -0.321304, -0.339475, -0.333965, -0.333335, -0.333333, \
-0.333333, -0.333333}`. And there is the N[z] in the function. What's happening?

Comment: @David, as noted, `DensityPlot[]` will attempt to symbolically analyze your function to try to plot it better, which is not appropriate here. Putting in the `_?NumericQ` check thwarts that automatic analysis, and tells `DensityPlot[]` to just concentrate on plotting it.