# How to plot fractals created with Newton's method

Tags: fractals

I'm quite a beginner using *Mathematica*. I'd like to plot the fractals of higher degree polynomials.

I have an example for `z^3 - 1` which looks like this:

```
F[z_] := z^3 - 1;
NewtonRaphsonStep[z_] := z - F[z]/F'[z]
NoOfIterations = 6; 
GridSize = .01
MatrixPlot[
  Table[
    θ = Arg[Nest[NewtonRaphsonStep, i + j I, NoOfIterations] /. 
      {Indeterminate -> 10}]; 
    If[θ > 1.8, 1, If[θ < -1.8, 2, 0]], 
    {j, -2., 2., GridSize}, {i, -2., 2., GridSize}], 
  Mesh -> None, Mesh -> False, ImageSize -> {500, 500}, 
  ColorRules -> {2 -> Red, 0 -> Orange, 1 -> Pink}]
```

And this works just fine. But for `z^4 - 1` and higher degrees, I don't know how to plot the fractal, I'm not sure how to handle more roots.

Could you help me please?

Comment: Have you searched on this site? Have you seen [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/100053/my-introduction-to-compile) and other related posts?

Answer (score 6):

Here is a simpler `ListDensityPlot` version using `FixedPoint` and avoiding indeterminate values by choosing a step size which skips `0 + 0 I`. It is also much faster by mapping over precomputed coordinates.

```
ListDensityPlot[Arg @ FixedPoint[NewtonRaphsonStep, #] & /@ 
   Table[i + j I, {j, -2., 2., 0.011}, {i, -2., 2., 0.011}], 
     ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"]
```

[image]

Comment: Looks quite like this answer: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/100055  ;)

Comment: Oh, thanks, the link also answers the question how to plot z^4 etc.

Comment: I'm still trying to decide if it's a duplicate.  With new users, I like to give them a chance to respond before I vote.