# Basins of attraction using Newton's method

Tags: graphics, fractals

In this question [Original Post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15047/how-to-draw-fractal-images-of-iteration-functions-on-the-riemann-sphere) the user provides a working Mathematica code which plots the basins of attraction using the Newton's iteration method. However the code works only for the function $p(z) = z^3 - 1$.

So my question is what should be changed in the code so as to work with any type of $p(z)$ function (i.e., $p(z) = z^5 -1$, $p(z) = z^2 - 2^z$, etc)?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Change the first line of the code `f = Function[z, z^3 - 1];`

Comment: @Saurav And then what? The rest of the code uses `p[z]`.

Comment: It should be clear from the warning *Part::partw: Part 5 of {{cc,0,0},{cc,cc,0},{0,0,cc}} does not exist.* that the problem lies in the definition of `colorList` - it assumes three roots. I suggest changing it to something like `colorList = ColorConvert[Hue /@ (Range[numRoots]/numRoots), "RGB"] /. RGBColor[x__] :> cc {x}`

Comment: @SimonWoods It does not work with other types of functions. Check it out. And for $z^3-1$ the output comes in black and white.

Comment: @Vaggelis_Z, it works fine for me. Here is the [result](http://i.stack.imgur.com/BuTuu.png) for `p[z_]:=z^5-1`

Comment: @SimonWoods Could you post the entire code? What version do you have? I have v 9.0.

Comment: The first thing [my answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15047/how-to-draw-fractal-images-of-iteration-functions-on-the-riemann-sphere/16900#16900) to that question does is generalize the code to arbitrary functions. I guess that's what @Saurav is referring to.

Comment: The entire code is just the original question code with the altered definition of `colorList`. Anyway, why not just use the much improved code from Mark McClure's answer there? It works for different functions without any alteration.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
newton[z_] := z - f[z]/f'[z]

plot[r_] :=
 ListDensityPlot[Arg@FixedPoint[newton, #, 50] & /@
   Table[i + j I, {j, -r, r, 2 r/365.}, {i, -r, r, 2 r/365.}],
  ColorFunction -> "Rainbow",
  DataRange -> {{-r, r}, {-r, r}}]

f[z_] := z^3 - 1; plot[2.0]
```

[image]

```
 f[z_] := z^5 - 1; plot[2.0]
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice! I have a couple of question: (i) You define a grid of initial conditions in the square [-2,2] however the range in the plot is from 0 to about 350. Why? I should be from -2 to 2 on both axes. (ii) Can your code generate the output for $f(z) = z^2 - 2^z$ shown here: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NewtonsMethod.html (last figure, left panel)

Comment: Must leave. Will answer/modify later

Comment: @Vaggelis_Z `plot := ListDensityPlot[{Re[#], Im[#],  Arg@FixedPoint[newton, #, 50]} & /@  Flatten@Table[i + j I, {j, -2., 2., 0.011}, {i, -2., 2., 0.011}], ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"]`

Comment: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/100786/5478

Comment: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/100055/5478

Comment: @mmal Your suggestion needs much more CPU time than eldo's. Why? And what if I want RGB colors instead of Rainbow?

Comment: And what if I want RGB colors instead of Rainbow? Could you please take a look here http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/101266/basins-of-attraction-using-newtons-method-part-ii where your method seems not to working?