# Basins of attraction using Newton's method Part II

Tags: plotting, graphics, fractals

For the function

$F(z;Q,a) = 3z - \frac{z}{|z|^3}\left(1 + \frac{3a}{2|z|^2}\right) - Q$

the Newton iteration formula is

$z_{n+1} = z_n - \frac{F(z_n;Q,a)}{F_z(z_n,a)} = \frac{2Qz_n^4|z_n|+6z_n^3+15az_n}{2(3z_n^4|z_n|+2z_n^2+6a)}$

For $a = 0.5$ and $Q = 2$ the basins of attraction are the following

[image]

where the black dots indicate the position of the six attractors.

```
F = 3*z - z/((Norm[z])^3)*(1 + (3*a)/(2*(Norm[z])^2)) - Q;
a = 0.5; Q = 2;

zn1 = (2*Q*z^4*Norm[z] + 6*z^3 + 15 a*z)/(2*(3*z^4*Norm[z] + 2*z^2 + 6*a));
```

I used the code suggested by @eldo here: [code](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/101255/basins-of-attraction-using-newtons-method)

```
newton[z_] := z - f[z]/f'[z]

plot := ListDensityPlot[Arg@FixedPoint[newton, #, 50] & /@ 
 Table[i + j I, {j, -2., 2., 0.1}, {i, -2., 2., 0.1}], 
 ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"]

f[z_] := 3*z - z/((Norm[z])^3)*(1 + (3*a)/(2*(Norm[z])^2)) - Q;
a = 0.5; Q = 2; plot
```

but the program seems not not to respond. I waited for more than ten minutes but no output was arrived. I think the `Norm[]` creates some problems but I am not so sure about it.

Am I doing something wrong? Can anyone please help me to produce this plot with Mathematica?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: You have asked [a similar question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/101255/basins-of-attraction-using-newtons-method) that received answers that work with many function forms. Unless you explain what you have tried and why exactly those methods don't work for you in this case, I would consider this question a duplicate of that one.

Comment: @MarcoB Thank you very much for pointing out this! See my revised post.

Comment: For complicated functions like this one you should download the notebook in http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NewtonsMethod.html and become familiar with its coding.

Comment: @eldo I experimented with the suggested notebook without success.

Comment: I'll try tomorrow because it is a time consuming task

Comment: Examine `f'[z]`.  Neither `Norm` nor `Abs` are differentiable.  Maybe code the formula explicitly.

Comment: It might help if you show us where you obtained the image you wish to recreate.

Comment: I agree with Quantum_Oli - it would be nice to know where this came from. It appears there might be an interesting question here but the image looks like the Julia set of a polynomial - I can't imagine how your non-differentiable function generated it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I visited the Weinstein page [http ://mathworld.wolfram.com/NewtonsMethod.html](http://http%20:%20//%20mathworld.wolfram.com/NewtonsMethod.html) and simplified their coding to

```
newton[f_] := z - (f - 1)/D[f, z] /. z :> #
```

Coming back to your last question we can now plot

```
fun = newton[z^2 - 2^z]
```

[image]

```
grays = GrayLevel /@ Join[Range[1., 0., -0.1], Range[0.1, 1., 0.1]];

DensityPlot[
 Length@FixedPointList[fun &, x + I y, 20, SameTest -> (Abs[#1 - #2] < 10^-6 &)],
 {y, -12, 12}, {x, -12, 12},
 PlotPoints -> 150,
 ColorFunction -> (Blend[grays, Abs@#] &),
 ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

Now to this question. As @MichaelE2 already commented "neither `Norm` nor `Abs` are differentiable." Consequently I don't know how the image you show was plotted.
Leaving the `Abs` away we get the following picture:

```
fun = newton[3 z - z/(z^3) (1 + 3 a/(2 z^2)) - Q /. {a -> 0.5, Q -> 2}] // Simplify;

DensityPlot[
 Length@FixedPointList[fun &, x + I y, 20, SameTest -> (Abs[#1 - #2] < 10^-6 &)],
 {y, -2, 2}, {x, -2, 2},
 PlotPoints -> 150,
 ColorFunction -> (Blend[grays, Abs@#] &),
 ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

**Update**

If you want to colorize you can use one of the many inbuilt color schemes (see `ColorData` in the doc)

```
fun = newton[z^2 - 2^z];

DensityPlot[
 Length@FixedPointList[fun &, x + I y, 20, SameTest -> (Abs[#1 - #2] < 10^-6 &)],
 {y, -12, 12}, {x, -12, 12},
 PlotPoints -> 150,
 ColorFunction -> "ThermometerColors",
 ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

Or use `Hue`

```
DensityPlot[
 Length@FixedPointList[fun &, x + I y, 20, SameTest -> (Abs[#1 - #2] < 10^-6 &)],
 {y, -12, 12}, {x, -12, 12},
 PlotPoints -> 150,
 ColorFunction -> (Hue[#, 1, 0.75] &),
 ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

Comment: Why did you choose Gray instead of nice colors? Second and most important. The second plot is not the same with the one I posted. You define `fun = newton[3 z - z/(z^3) (1 + 3 a/(2 z^2)) - Q /. {a -> 0.5, Q -> 2}] // Simplify;` however you don't take into account that in the first and second terms containing the `z` variable it should be `Norm[z]` instead of simple `z`. I suppose this leads to another type of plot.

Comment: As @MichaelE2 already commented "neither Norm nor Abs are differentiable." Consequently I don't know how the image you show was calculated / plotted.

Comment: One last issue and I will approve your answer. Could you use RGB colors in the plots instead of the gray levels?

Comment: Nice job! I will try to find out what is going on with the `Norm[z]`.