# Basins of attraction when using Newton's method to solve $x^3-1 = 0$

Tags: fractals

I created Newton fractal plot for `x^3 - 1` and would like to know where did I go wrong. I know I could have just copied the code but that would not have been fun.

```
x = N[FindDivisions[{-2, 2}, 200], 8];
y = N[FindDivisions[{-2, 2}, 200], 8];
fx = xn^3 - 1;
f1x = 3*xn^2;
r = {};
r2 = {};
r3 = {};

i = 1;
j = 1;
iter = 1;
For[i = 1, i < 200,
 xi = x[[i]];
 For[j = 1, j < 200,
   yi = y[[j]];
   xn = xi + I*yi;
   For[iter = 1, iter < 7,
     xn1 = N[xn - fx/f1x, 8];
     xn = xn1;
     iter++;
     ]
    Which[Im[xn] < 0`10, AppendTo[r, {x[[i]], y[[j]]}], Im[xn] > 0`10,
       AppendTo[r2, {x[[i]], y[[j]]}], Im[xn] == 0`10, 
     AppendTo[r3, {x[[i]], y[[j]]}]]
    j++;
   ]
  i++;]

a = ListPlot[r, PlotStyle -> Red];
b = ListPlot[r2, PlotStyle -> Blue];
c = ListPlot[r3, PlotStyle -> Green];
Show[a, b, c]
```

As you can see it looks similar but not exactly like the required one. Would like to know what I can do to make it better. Should I increase the number of test cases? Would it help?

[image: basins_of_attraction]

Comment: You write: "As you can see it looks similar but not exactly like the required one. ". No, I can't see that as you supply no "required one" to compare it to.

Comment: See: [100053](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/100053/5478), [15047](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/15047/5478)

Comment: Hint. Your use of arbitrary precision arithmetic at low precision is not speeding up your code. Machine arithmetic is always the fastest way to compute.

Comment: More hints: Your For-loop syntax is incorrect -- your iterator increments should be given as the 3rd argument to `For`. You are a missing the semi-colon needed to separate your `Which` expression from For-loop that precedes it.

Comment: how to located three roots in the second picture. could you tell me how does it make in matlab?

Answer (score 10):

Just to illustrate avoidance of `For` loop, use of `MatrixPlot` (requires change of representation):

```
f[z_] := z - (z^3 - 1)/(3 z^2)
roots = {{1, 0}, {-1/2, Sqrt[3]/2}, {-1/2, -Sqrt[3]/2}};
nt[x_, y_, n_] := 
 FixedPoint[f[Complex @@ #] &, {x, y}, n] /. Complex[a_, b_] :> {a, b}
cfn[x_, y_, n_] := 
 With[{r = nt[x, y, n]}, Which[Norm[r - {1, 0}] < 10^(-6), 1,
   Norm[r - {-1/2., Sqrt[3]/2.}] < 10^(-6), 2, 
   Norm[r - {-1/2., -Sqrt[3]/2.}] < 10^(-6), 3]]
Legended[MatrixPlot[
  Reverse@Transpose@
    Table[cfn[i, j, 40], {i, -2, 2, 0.015}, {j, -2, 2, 0.015}], 
  DataRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}}, 
  ColorRules -> {1 -> Red, 2 -> Green, 3 -> Blue}, 
  Epilog -> {Yellow, PointSize[0.02], Point[roots]}], 
 SwatchLegend[{Red, Green, Blue}, Style[#1 + #2 I, 20] & @@@ roots]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You need a lot more iterations at a lot more points to get a good image of the basins of attraction. With a faster implementation than yours, I was able to get a reasonably good image when iterating 15 times at 250,000 points (500 x 500 lattice).

I also think your code may have bugs that are distorting the image, so I'm not sure you will get a correct image even if you increase the number of iterations and use more points.

This is the image my code produces.

[image]

#### Update

I have two sets of code that can generate the above image. The 1st is a repaired and speeded up version of the OP's code. I don't recommend using this code, but it might be instructive to the OP and others to see what is more or less the minimum needed to make the posted code work.

```
fx[u_] := u^3 - 1;
f1x[u_] := 3 u^2;

n = 500;
y = x = Subdivide[-2., 2., n];
max = 15;
r1 = r2 = r3 = r[];

For[i = 1, i <= n + 1, i++,
  xi = x[[i]];
  For[j = 1, j <= n + 1, j++,
    xn = xi + I*y[[j]];
    Quiet @ 
      For[iter = 1, iter < max, iter++,
        xn1 = xn - fx[xn]/f1x[xn];
        xn = xn1];
    imxn = Im[xn];
    Which[
      imxn == 0., r3 = r[{x[[i]], y[[j]]}, r3],
      imxn < 0., r1 = r[{x[[i]], y[[j]]}, r1],
      imxn > 0., r2 = r[{x[[i]], y[[j]]}, r2]]]]
```

Accumulating the deeply nested `r` expressions is much faster than the `AppendTo`s the OP was using to accumulate basin points. This is a major speed boost.

We must flatten the results afterward, but that too is fast.

```
pts = List @@@ (Flatten @* r /@ {r1, r2, r3});

a = ListPlot[pts[[1]], PlotStyle -> Blue];
b = ListPlot[pts[[2]], PlotStyle -> Yellow];
c = ListPlot[pts[[3]], PlotStyle -> Red];
Show[a, b, c,
  Axes -> None,
  AspectRatio -> Automatic,
  ImageSize -> Large]
```

The 2nd code set is the one I recommend. This, in essence, remains a straight-forward translation of OP's code, preserving the the basic procedural approach, but replacing elements of what I consider bad practice with code that is widely accepted as good practice. Note that I do not introduce any global variables. Only the function definitions are made at top-level.

```
fx[u_] := u^3 - 1;
f1x[u_] := 3 u^2;

With[{n = 500, max = 15},
  pts =
    Module[{x, b, b1, b2, b3, root, yRoot},
      x = Subdivide[-2., 2., n];
      b3 = b2 = b1 = b[];
      Do[
       root = Quiet @ Nest[# - f[#]/df[#] &, x[[i]] + I x[[j]], max];
       yRoot = Im[root];
       Which[
         yRoot == 0., b1 = b[{x[[i]], x[[j]]}, b1],
         yRoot < 0., b2 = b[{x[[i]], x[[j]]}, b2],
         yRoot > 0., b3 = b[{x[[i]], x[[j]]}, b3]],
      {i, n + 1}, {j, n + 1}];
    List @@@ (Flatten @* b /@ {b1, b2, b3})]];
```

`Do` and `Nest` are faster than `For`, and only one `Do` expression is needed. Further, since the point lattice being constructed is the same in both directions, only one list of divisions is needed.

```
ListPlot[{pts[[1]], pts[[2]], pts[[3]]},
  PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue, Yellow},
  Axes -> None,
  AspectRatio -> Automatic,
  ImageSize -> Large]
```

`Show` is not needed.

Comment: Would you mind sharing it?

Comment: @user49702. What are you asking me to share? Your "it" is a pronoun with no reference

Comment: Perhaps, the OP is referring to the code you used to produce your plot.

Comment: @bbgodfrey.  Probably. But it is not perfectly clear and I think it should be. I don't want to make an effort only to be told what I posted wasn't what was asked for. (Happened to me more than once already)

Comment: @user49702. I am willing to post my code if you will confirm that is what you are asking me to do.

Comment: I am asking you to post the code you used to generate the fractal you produced. 
Thanks

Comment: @user49702. Done

Comment: update: I wanted to expand the code for 2 point methods like Jarratt or Ostrowski type methods, is it possible? I tried but the execution time is quite long for that program.

Comment: @user49702. That is a whole new question and should not be addressed to me in a comment. It should be posted as new question for whole community to see.